# Cargar resultado de una query en un tabla con angular

Tags: angular, webservice, async

Estoy trabajando en una pantalla que esta compuesta por varios componentes, uno es el filtro de búsqueda y el otro es una tabla que mostrara el resultado de una consulta a una BBDD de oracle.

La tabla siempre esta pintada en pantalla pero cuando se devuelve el resultado de la query debe actualizarse y pintar los resultados obtenidos y aquí tengo el problema soy nuevo con angular y no se como puedo hacer eso. He buscado por Internet pero las soluciones que he visto no termino de hacerlas funcionar.

filtroBusqueda.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { BusquedaServiceService } from '../../../services/busquedaService/busqueda-service.service';
import { Busqueda } from 'src/app/model/busqueda';

@Component({
   selector: "app-buscador-principal",
   templateUrl: "./buscador-principal.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./buscador-principal.component.css"]
})
export class BuscadorPrincipalComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() emitResultadoBusqueda: EventEmitter<Busqueda>;

constructor(private _busquedaServiceService: BusquedaServiceService) {
    this.emitResultadoBusqueda = new EventEmitter();
}

getValoresComponent() {

    this._busquedaServiceService.busqueda(JSON.stringify(this.busqueda)).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.emitResultadoBusqueda.emit(resp);
    });
}
```

El método getValoresComponent() es el que envía los filtros por los que se quiere buscar en la BBDD de oracle (he omitido todo el código de esa parte).

this._busquedaServiceService.busqueda lanza el servicio que consulta en BBDD y recibe resp que es el resultado de la BBDD.

componentePadre.component.html

```
<div class="row" id="body-row">
<app-menuLateral></app-menuLateral>
<!-- MAIN -->
<div class="container col mt-3">
    <div class="container">
        <app-buscador-principal (emitResultadoBusqueda) = "resultadoBusqueda = $event"></app-buscador-principal>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-5">
                <!-- Este es el div de contenido con scroll -->
                <h5 class="border-bottom border-success mt-3 mb-3">Resultados</h5>
                <app-tabla></app-tabla>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-menuFAB></app-menuFAB>
```

En el padre escucho el evento emitido por el hijo

componentePadre.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Busqueda } from 'src/app/model/busqueda';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-historico',
  templateUrl: './historico.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./historico.component.css']
})
export class HistoricoComponent implements OnInit {

  resultadoBusqueda: Busqueda;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

En el componente tabla ahora mismo tengo datos añadidos manualmente pero quiero que cargue los devueltos por el padre

tabla.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Busqueda } from 'src/app/model/busqueda';

@Component({
    selector: "app-tabla",
    templateUrl: "./tabla.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./tabla.component.css"]
})
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() ots: Busqueda;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    /*this.ots = [
        { numero: "000174585", tipo: "DPRP-DR1", estado: true, fecha: "10/03/2020" },
        { numero: "00025", tipo: "DPRP-DR3", estado: false, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254786", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254787", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254475", tipo: "DOPL-DO1", estado: false, fecha: "11/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254788", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254789", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254790", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: false, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254791", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254792", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254793", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254794", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254795", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254796", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: false, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254797", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254798", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254799", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" },
        { numero: "000254800", tipo: "DPRN-DR3", estado: true, fecha: "09/03/2020" }
    ];*/
}
}
```

tabla.component.html

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="ots" dataKey="numero" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngIf="collapsibles" style="width: 3em;" [attr.rowspan]="2" scope="row">
            <a href="importacion">
                <em class="fa fa-minus colorVerde"></em>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th *ngIf="checkboxes" style="width: 3em;" [attr.rowspan]="2" scope="row">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkboxGeneral">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkboxGeneral"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th *ngIf="colHistorio" style="width: 10em;" [attr.rowspan]="2" scope="row"></th>

        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" scope="row">
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field" scope="row">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'numero'" class="form-control inputMini" type="text" placeholder="000000000">
            <select *ngSwitchCase="'tipo'" class="browser-default custom-select inputMini">
                <option>Seleccionar Tipo...</option>
                <option>DCO</option>
                <option>DOPL</option>
                <option>DPRN</option>
            </select>
            <select *ngSwitchCase="'estado'" class="browser-default custom-select inputMini">
                <option>Seleccionar Estado...</option>
                <option>OK</option>
                <option>KO</option>
            </select>
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'fecha'" class="form-control inputMini" type="date"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
    <tr [ngClass]="rowData.estado ? null : 'ibg_red_error'">
        <td *ngIf="collapsibles">
            <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
                <em [ngClass]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'" class="colorVerde"></em>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="checkboxes">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="rowData.numero">
                <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="rowData.numero"></label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="colHistorio" style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="mr-3 colorVerde" >
                <em class="fa fa-eye iconTabla"></em>
            </a>
            <a class="colorRojo">
                <em class="fa fa-trash iconTabla"></em>
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            {{rowData.numero}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{rowData.tipo}}
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="rowData.estado; else estadoKO" class="ibd_green_success">
            OK
        </td>
        <ng-template #estadoKO>
            <td class="ibd_red_error">
                KO
            </td>
        </ng-template>
        <td>
            {{rowData.fecha}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData>
    <tr>
        <td [attr.colspan]="setAttrColspan()">
            <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md">
                    <div class="ui-g">
                        <div class="list-group ui-g-12">
                            <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <p class="mb-0">AUFNR - 00025</p>
                                    <small *ngIf="rowData.estado; else estadoKO" class="ibd_green_success">OK</small>
                                    <ng-template #estadoKO>
                                        <small #estadoKO class="ibd_red_error">KO</small>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </div>
                                <small>Longitud no válida.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <p class="mb-0">HOJARUTA - null</p>
                                    <small *ngIf="rowData.estado; else estadoKO" class="ibd_green_success">OK</small>
                                    <ng-template #estadoKO>
                                        <small #estadoKO class="ibd_red_error">KO</small>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </div>
                                <small>Atributo con valor null.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <p class="mb-0">FNO_UT - 23</p>
                                    <small *ngIf="rowData.estado; else estadoKO" class="ibd_green_success">OK</small>
                                    <ng-template #estadoKO>
                                        <small #estadoKO class="ibd_red_error">KO</small>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </div>
                                <small>Longitud no válida.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <p class="mb-0">FID_UT - null</p>
                                    <small *ngIf="rowData.estado; else estadoKO" class="ibd_green_success">OK</small>
                                    <ng-template #estadoKO>
                                        <small #estadoKO class="ibd_red_error">KO</small>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </div>
                                <small>Atributo con valor null.</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Cuando se inicializa el componente tabla no tiene datos y cuando si tiene datos no se pintan. Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que pasar los datos al componente `app-tabla` que recibes de tu backend. Y por lo que veo tu componente `app-tabla` no tienen ningun `@Input` que se llame `colHistorio` y esto puede provocar errores.

Como ya tienes un `@Input` en `app-tabla` para pasar los datos de la búsqueda pues añades eso y te debería funcionar si tienes la template correcta.

```
<div class="row" id="body-row">
<app-menuLateral></app-menuLateral>
<!-- MAIN -->
<div class="container col mt-3">
    <div class="container">
        <app-buscador-principal (emitResultadoBusqueda) = "resultadoBusqueda = $event"></app-buscador-principal>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-5">
                <!-- Este es el div de contenido con scroll -->
                <h5 class="border-bottom border-success mt-3 mb-3">Resultados</h5>
                <app-tabla [ots]="resultadoBusqueda"></app-tabla>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-menuFAB></app-menuFAB>
```

Para ver que datos te llegan al input puedes hacer log con metodo `ngOnChanges`(lifecycle method)

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-tabla",
    templateUrl: "./tabla.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./tabla.component.css"]
})
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() ots: Busqueda;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // lo que tengas
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: No he puesto todo el código , solo el referente a mi problema actual pero si tengo un @input que se llama colHistorico.

Comment: he puesto lo que me comentas y sigo sin ver los resultados en la tabla.

Comment: pero como renderizas los datos en tu template de `app-tabla` no lo has puesto. Y el `getValoresComponent` donde lo llamas.

Comment: Ya he puesto el tablaComponent.html, es un diseño que no he creado yo pero tengo que trabajar con eso, va a pintar el contenido de la variable ots del controlador. los valores que tengo que pintar en el componente tabla los obtengo en filtroBusqueda.component.ts

Comment: la template es bastante compleja he actualizado mi respuesta puedes ver los datos que te llegan en input `ots` y así transformar los datos para que se renderizen en la template.

Comment: una pregunta, esa función (ngOnChanges) se ejecuta solo cuando se carga por primera vez la pantalla y no cuando he obtenido los resultados que quiero mostrar ¿Estarán llegando los datos al input ots?

Comment: esa función se ejecuta siempre que el input cambia su valor. Cuando digo input me refiero los datos que pasas del padre al hijo. En tu caso como pides los datos al backend el ngOnInit del componente hijo ya se ha ejecutado porque aun no has recibido los datos del backend. Por eso, en el `ngOnChanges` tienes acceso a los datos cuando el padre los setee de nuevo. Aquí tienes los metodos de ciclo de vida de un componente https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: entonces debería volver a entrar cuando se obtienen esos datos y no lo esta haciendo.

Comment: pues así sin mas no puedo saber lo que pasa. He creado esta demo para que veas como funciona https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq3w2j

Comment: no te preocupes, voy analizar tu demo por si me aclaro algo. Muchísimas gracias, me has ayudado mucho!!